# Jmeter and mobile app

Tags: jmeter

Hellow
I have a laptop with jmeter running and a mobile, both connected to the same wifi. I try to record some mobile internet apps, but jmeter doesn´t record anything. I´ve set the laptop´s IP addres as mobile´s proxy, and jmeter´s port as mobile´s proxy port, but when I do this internet stops working. Please, some help. Whath am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many possible reasons, you should specify your mobile OS along with version and show proxy and JMeter configurations.

In the meantime quick checklist:

1. Use your browser to navigate to any site using **HTTP** protocol. If JMeter is not recording - something is wrong with your configuration (ports mismatch, JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is not running, proxy settings on mobile device are incorrect, etc)
2. If you can record browser actions but cannot record the application it might be the case that application is using **HTTPS** protocol. In that case you will need to install JMeter certificate (the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and is being generated in JMeter's "bin" folder when you start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder) onto mobile device.
3. Some mobile operating systems don't send HTTPS traffic over proxy, you may need to use 3rd-party applications for configuring system-wide HTTPS proxy (i.e. [ProxyDroid for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en_GB))

If above suggestions don't work (they should) you can consider [alternative solutions of recording mobile device HTTP(S) traffic and converting it into a JMeter test script](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-).